# Can't mount USB Drive - Is it dead?

Tags: linux, usb, removable-media

I've been trying to mount a USB drive which was interrupted during a file transfer on a windows machine without much luck. Below are the details of some of the things that I've tried:

- Windows Explorer gives nothing (although a usb connected sound does play)
- Windows diskpart does not show the drive
- Similarly, GUI Disk management does not show the drive

On linux,

- I am able to see the USB device in lsusb, output:

```
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 090c:2000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) USB DISK
```

- I can also see it when I use lsblk, this device is sda:

```
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    1 234.4G  0 disk
└─sda1         8:1    1 234.4G  0 part
mmcblk0      179:0    0  58.2G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1  179:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─mmcblk0p2  179:2    0  57.8G  0 part /
```

- Attempting to mount the device hangs my terminal
- dmesg gives the following:

```
[ 1216.190465] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 491519952 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 1257.791038] xhci_hcd 0000:00:10.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1263.166781] xhci_hcd 0000:00:10.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[ 1263.378716] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 6, error -62
[ 1267.622776] usb 3-1: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 1267.647746] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1267.647757] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1267.647764] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 512 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
```

- Unfortunately, fdisk hangs indefinitely when attempting to either list or interact with /dev/sda1
- I also gave ntfsfix a try, but it hangs when attempting to mount.

I suppose my question is: is this device dead? Ideally I'd like to recover the files, but would also be interested in reformatting for later use if possible.

Comment: Not an answer, but if you are willing to invest a little money into a "hard drive dock" or "drive docking station", you can probably answer whether or not the drive is shot yourself. Personally, I had an external drive where the drive ended up being relatively ok (I could salvage files, etc.) but the controller for the case/interface exhibited all kinds of problems when connecting the drive to the PC through it. Removing the drive from the orginal case and using a drive docking station allowed me to salvage files and use the drive for a bit longer.

Comment: @Anaksunaman removing an external drive from its case may work when the drive has a SATA interface and there is a SATA to USB interface adapter, but many external hard drives now have a simpler arrangement with USB chip directly on the hard drive PCB so no docking would be possible. I have a WD Elements drive that is such a device. To get data from it I would need to buy an identical drive and swap the PCB. Not economic.

Comment: Have you tried gparted? If it can be viewed there, you can try deleting all partitions and recreating one (FAT32, probably). Of course that destroys all data,  but could let you reuse the device.,

Comment: "which was interrupted during a file transfer" Yes it killed it.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts everyone. Looks like I'll need to accept my loss on this one and just get a new drive. It was probably time anyways.